# Who would have used this c1890s canvas bag?

Tags: united-states, military

I have an OLD canvas bag measuring 14 x 11", opens to two pouches. It has a leather strap on the back that makes it look like it was possibly used as a backpack.

Printed on the front is "2 SEP.CO.   16".

Inside is stamped "Ridabock & Co., 141 Grand St., New York". There is a second stamp, most of which is too faded for me to read, but I can make out "Sep 1896".

I have researched this company and see that it was at that address (141 Grand) in the 1890s. (photo of an ad I found is included, which also states that the company are "Manufacturers of Military goods of every description, U.S. Army Officers Regulation Equipments a specialty", from march 1894 Army & Navy Journal).  The last mention I can find of Ridabock at that address is 1896.

I find references to "Sep. Co." as Army "Separate Company", but I can't really find anything in particular beyond that to explain who might have used this.

So I think this item probably dates to the time frame.  Can anyone speculate on  what this type of bag might have been used for, and by whom?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The "Second Separate Company" (of infantry) seems to have been part of the New York National Guard, headquartered in Auburn: https://books.google.com/books?id=x1gTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA830&lpg=PA830&dq=%22second+separate+company%22&source=bl&ots=MoNM11VQVd&sig=ACfU3U32zy5SK5BYLZs8F7hQHesitMxSYg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJyfCxr6LmAhUkq1kKHfwJDLAQ6AEwAHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22second%20separate%20company%22&f=false